# Duplicating filename issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web page in which different user account can be created and the files created for individual user will be diaplayed in the gridview. That is, The files created by abc will be displayed in gridview when abc logs in. Whenever a user creates a file, these files are stored in a folder so that whenever the user clicks on the filename in the gridview the control goes to this folder to open it. So now my question is how can I manage the duplication of the filename. that is, If the user abc creates a filename "Lion", this will be stored in the folder and also in the database and will be displayed to abc when he/she logs in. Now another user say xyz wants to create the the same filename "Lion" which is going to store in the same folder, then that file created by abc will be replaced by the one created by xyz. How can I avoid this?

Comment: different folders for each user

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate folder for each user.

Comment: U mean to say if there are 20 users I need to create 20 folders.. that is not good.

Comment: @slm Why not?​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 1):

Have two columns in your database:

```
OriginalFilename NVARCHAR(255),
StoredFilename NVARCHAR(255)
```

When the a user stores a file, create a new name for it, maybe by using `Guid.New()` to ensure you have a unique name for it and save the file to the folder with that name. Insert a record into your database that saves the original name.

When a user asks for a list of their files, show them the `OriginalFIlename` column and when they download a file, access it by the `StoredFilename` column but send it down to them with the filename set to `OriginalFilename`.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the file should **not** be your primary key, just an additional column. For the file on disk you can just use a Guid or another unique key that references the row in the database, which in turn also holds the name of the file for display purposes only.

Comment: Storing in database is not a problem here. I'm storing all the files in a folder and then, only names in database. SO that when the filenames in the gridview are clicked the control is sent to the folder to open that file. I have also a facility that a user can share his files to other users. So if a filename "Moon" is present in one user's list and he shares that file with other user too then "Moon" will be included in other user's list too. So How can I manage?

Comment: when a user clicks on "moon" he really clicks on a file with an id of `42` and a *display name* of "moon". The ids are unique, the names are not.

Comment: Ya but I'm not storing the files(.docx, .xlsx, .pptx) in the database, so when the username click on the column in the gridview, the filename is taken to open that file from the folder. I hope u r understanding what I'm trying to tell. Or is it possible to store the files(.docx, .xlsx, .pptx) themselves in database with the content?

Answer (score 0):

So you basically need to write the logic that checks to see if the filename already exists. If it does exist, you need to change the file name so that it is unique. You can append a string to it (first few characters of a guid, time stamp, -1) or something similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder for each user, you can use the database to store the file display name and add to each file name a guid.

Answer (score 0):

If the users are supposed to see only their own individual files, then your app should create a uniquely-named folder for each user (probably using their record ID), so there will be no filename collisions.  You can also consider IsolatedStorage for this case.